# Explicitly defaulted copy/move assignment operators implicitly deleted because field has no copy/move operators. C++

Tags: c++, class, constants, copy-assignment, move-assignment-operator

I'm new to C++ and dont know why this is happening and how to fix it. Here's some snippets of the code:

header file:

```
class Dictionary{

    private:
        string filename;       
        const string theSeparators;   

    public:
        Dictionary(const string& filename, const string& separators = "\t\n");

        Dictionary() = delete;   

        ~Dictionary() = default; 

        Dictionary(const Dictionary&) = default; 

        Dictionary(Dictionary&&) = default;  

        Dictionary& operator=(const Dictionary&) = default; 
    
        Dictionary& operator=(Dictionary&&) = default;   
};
```

cpp file:

```
Dictionary::Dictionary(const string& filename, const string& separators = "\t\n"){

/* some stuff for the filename*/
}
```

> error: copy assignment operator of 'Dictionary' is implicitly deleted because field 'theSeparators' has no copy assignment operator
>
> ```
>    const string theSeparators;
> ```
>
> error:move assignment operator of 'Dictionary' is implicitly deleted because field 'theSeparators' has no move assignment operator
>
> ```
>    const string theSeparators;
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data member

```
 const string theSeparators;
```

is defined with the qualifier `const`. So it can not be reassigned after its initialization in a constructor.

Thus the compiler defined the copy and move assignment operators as deleted.

You can just remove the qualifier `const` for this data member.

Or if to keep the qualifier `const` for the data member then you have to use mem-initialing lists in constructors like for example

```
Dictionary::Dictionary(const string& filename, const string& separators = "\t\n")
    : filename( filename ), theSeparators( separators )
{
    //...
}
```

But in this case the copy and move assignment operators will be still deleted.

Comment: The const member is private so not accessible to users of the class. The only loss is the protection you get from inadvertently changing it when writing member methods. I find that annoying but for variables that aren't user accessible it's not worth the gyrations needed and they require you write custom assignment methods. And even that's only valid in c++20.